# Is this a normal tyre crack or something more sinister?

Tags: wheels

[image]

Hi,

My mother has found this crack on her Range Rover tyre. Her boyfriend has convinced her that it is normal and safe to drive on. However I am not convinced, as it looks far too straight. Especially the thin slit where it meets the tread. I am worried it has been done with a knife.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That tire has been cut and it is not safe to drive on.  Get it replaced ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

I’d say that tyre is completely knackered, even without the cut. Tyres just deteriorate over time and 5 or 6 years is about all that’s safe, even with minimal use, particularly for a heavy powerful car. Check the other tyres too, before it’s too late.

Answer (score 0):

That tire looks very old. Your mother needs to take it into a reputable tire shop. They can inspect the tires and see the age of them as well by the numbers on the side. This crack appears to be from age. Tires have a life span. Even if they are not used,  tires can become dangerous after 5 years of age. This is nothing to take chances with as a blowout can cause serious accidents. Let a professional diagnose these 4 tires.

Comment: What are the chances of receiving an unbiased evaluation of the problem from the person who will sell you a new tire (or set of)? I'd look for a professional that doesn't work on commission (or job advancement) at least.

Comment: @Jeeped knowing professionals that I can trust is handy - a professional opinion of “replace” or “keep” is so valuable - well worth the effort of keeping contact with them.